# return value from stored procedure

Tags: sql, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure like this:

```
Select @totalMoney*@bonusPercent/100
```

How i can return value from procedure and assign it to the varible?
i mean something like:

```
SET @myVarible = EXEC MyStoredProcedure @param1, @param1;
```

Comment: Why not use a user defined function instead of a stored procedure? (No SQL Server handy, so I can't write and test an example, sorry.) Easier to use within other stored procedures and functions. Harder to call from clients, so that's a trade off. If both other t-sql code and client needs access, I create the user defined function, then a stored procedure wrapper for the client.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use an `output` variable, return only works with integers

example

```
create procedure prTest @id int, @id2 decimal(20,10) output
as
select @id2 = @id + 1
go
```

now call it like this

```
declare @Test decimal(20,10)


exec prTest 5,@Test output
select @Test
```

output
6.00000000

Answer (score 1):

Within the stored procedure just use

```
 RETURN @X
```

`@X` must be an integer data type.

Return codes are normally used for status codes though. An output parameter may be a better choice dependant upon what you are doing exactly.

Declare the parameter as `OUTPUT`

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.MyStoredProcedure 
@param1 INT,
@myVarible DECIMAL(10,4) OUTPUT
AS 
...
```

and call it as

```
EXEC dbo.MyStoredProcedure @param1, @myVarible OUTPUT;
```